# Dart - Bitshift for Uint

Tags: dart, ffi

Try bitshifting for a Uint32 in Dart. How to handle this, if there is no support from dart:ffi?

```dart
import 'dart:ffi';


Uint32 len = 0 as Uint32;
len >>= 1; // will not be compiled
```

Try it with "normal" int. But i am afraid, will the result be everytime the same as using Uint32?

Comment: `Uint32` does not have a bitshift operator. FFI is for interfacing to C functions and the types defined in the FFI package are for marking type signatures in FFI interfaces. If you want to do a bitshift specifically on a 32 bit unsigned, you can make a C function to do that and link it through FFI. If you want to do a bitshift in Dart, just use the normal `int` type. The result will be nearly always be the same. Just take a look at the C spec and Dart docs to compare the operators to see differences. It would help to better understand your intentions so that we can help you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `Uint32` type represents native values. There is no Dart value with that type, so your `as Uint32` cast will fail.

If you have a `Pointer<Uint32>`, then you can use that to refer to the native value.
Example:

```dart
Pointer<Uint32> p = ...;
p.value >>= 1;
```